# Stop video sound on another tab selection

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tab Control in my application, when i click on first tab then video is playing, but when i click on another tab video sound is still played.

I want to stop video sound automatically when i click on another tab like a vine app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UITabBarControllerDelegate:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    if(viewController!=playerViewController){
        [self.videoPlayer stop];
    }
}
```

Or just stop videoPlayer in viewWillDisappear method:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [seuper viewWillDisappear: animated];
    [self.videoPlayer stop];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i tried this one but its not working for me.